# Selenium WebDriver loses information of New Window opened in IE

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

**Please don't dismiss this as a repeated question without reading it completely.**

**Scenario:**

I have to click a link on the HomePage of my application, which opens new Window. Once new window is opened, I need to do some operations on the web Elements on that page. This obviously is a common scenario every one of you generally deal with.

**Problem:**
After clicking on new window a new window is opened. And when performed driver.getWindowHandles(), it will give me 2(parent and child) windows initially. But within a second or two,even though the new window is still open, if I check for the windowHandles again it will return only one(the parentWindow).

To conclude the driver initially has the knowledge of a new window being opened, but somehow in a second or so it looses the details of second window and says only one window is present. And it is impossible to switch to a new window because of this reason. Obviously works fine in CHROME, but this has to be tested on IE.

**My piece of code:**

sysout(driver.getWindowHandle());// gives: [WINDOW_PARENT]

-- perform click on a link opened a new Window.

sysout(driver.getWindowHandles());  //gives: [WINDOW_PARENT, WINDOW_CHILD]

thread.sleep(1000);

sysout(driver.getWindowHandles());  //gives: [WINDOW_PARENT] --child is lost

--

**Tried on:**

IE-8/10/11- 32 bit

Selenium-java - prettymuch tried all starting 2.4

Comment: You have all the protected mode/enhanced protected mode settings correct per the documentation?

Comment: @Paut Abbott, Appreciate your quick response.   I do think Protected mode setting might be a reason here. But due to some restrictions in my organization, I cannot change those settings. I am going with a work around of INTRODUCE_FLAKENESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS.

Answer (score 0):

It worked. 
It's just the protection mode setting on IE.Once I changed it to be the same for all the security zones, it worked perfectly.

The reason for multiple windows being detected for a short while earlier with out this change was: because of a short time span between clicking the link and the Protection mode on IE coming into play.

Believe me guys what ever the problem with IE and selenium, the first thing you should be checking is the **protection mode settings**